# SUM different queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

Good afternoon everyone,

For a project on my internship, I am making a dashboard for the game we play in the break. We play darts, FIFA & billiards.

For example:

```
SELECT pw.name AS `winner`
     , COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM billiard_games g 
  JOIN players p1 
    ON p1.id = g.player_1 
  JOIN players p2 
    ON p2.id = g.player_2 
  LEFT 
  JOIN billiard_winners w 
    ON w.id = g.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN players pw 
    ON pw.id = w.winner 
 GROUP 
    BY winner
```

That outpust the following result:

```
Winner | Total
---------------
Name1 | 5
Name2 | 7
```

That means name1 won 5 times and name2 won 7 times. So far so good?

I have different queries for the other games. On the query above, I am asking for billiard_games. The other queries are the same but instead of billiard_games, I am asking dart_games & fifa_game.

On the front page of the application, I want a big overview. With the all time winners. This table need to count ALL the wins of one player. So the wins of FIFA, Billiard & Darts all togheter.

I tried this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM billiard_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN billiard_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner GROUP BY winner)+
(SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM dart_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN dart_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner GROUP BY winner)+
(SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM fifa_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN fifa_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner GROUP BY winner)
AS SumCount
```

This however doesn't work. Can anyone help me? I want ALL the names and ALL the wins in one view.

Comment: Your current SQL queries look quite convoluted.  Please add sample data to your question for best results here.

Comment: How do you mean sample data? EDIT: I asked for a query that outputs the names instead of the ID's on this forum, and received this anwer for the query

Comment: You can add a DBFiddle.

Comment: provide sample database... your tables and records

Comment: Almost have the solution. If needed I while post it. Thank you already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `UNION ALL`

```
select winner, sum(total)
from
(
SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM billiard_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN billiard_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner GROUP BY winner
union all
SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM dart_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN dart_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner 
GROUP BY winner
union all
SELECT pw.name AS `winner`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM fifa_games g INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player_1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player_2 LEFT JOIN fifa_winners w ON w.id = g.id LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner 
GROUP BY winner
) A group by winner
```

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL` here equal counts will be be removed when using `union`.

Comment: It does solve it. In my application, it isn't showing the numbers tho. <td><?php echo $c['total']; ?></td> doesn't return the numbers of wins. Dont know why to be honest. EDIT: Got it, thanks, its working!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT pw.name AS 'winner', COUNT(pw.name) AS total 
FROM billiard_games g 
INNER JOIN players p1 
ON p1.id = g.player_1 
INNER JOIN players p2 
ON p2.id = g.player_2 
LEFT JOIN billiard_winners w 
ON w.id = g.id 
LEFT JOIN players pw ON pw.id = w.winner GROUP BY winner
```

Comment: Most likely you need to do `COUNT(DISTINCT pw.name)` instead a COUNT on joins can multiply the count because the JOIN 's can return multiple records.

Comment: Please  pw.name add also in group by. So,it's working fine

Comment: "Please pw.name add also in group by. So,it's working fine" Why? this query is correct @HemangAghera `pw.name AS 'winner'` -> `GROUP BY winner` you know aliases and how MySQL handles them?

Answer (score 0):

Quite complex explanation though in order to run your query remove `+` and try to use `union` like `Select * from (<your_query_with_+changed_to_union>)` to atleast run it.

Comment: `Select * from (<your_query_with_+changed_to_union>)` What this fill in the blanks answer?.. You post it as a answer but you do not attempt to answer the question..

Comment: perhaps that was a long query and i am using mob as of now be the reason i din write the query but my say was OP has used `+` to add the selects output which is wrong hence my answer says to union all types of winners count.

Comment: Please explain further what should be done to solve the problem - which `+` should be removed where?